# Search tool that uses a grammar rather than regular expression?

Tags: search, grammar

Are there any search tools that allow you to set up a simple token/grammar parsing system that work similar to regular expressions?

What we want to do is search our ColdFusion code for queries that do not have cfqueryparams in them.

A regular expression gets a bit tough in this situation because I can't keep track of the start tags while looking for something else before getting an end tag.

It seems like a parsing system would work more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing it is XML, I would just use XSLT.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand wouldn't XSLT basically be "Building a parser"?  Also, what are you saying is XML?  ColdFusion is not.

Comment: I am really confused now how you can say it is not XML, all the sample code I can find is XML based!

Comment: CFML is tag based in the same way the HTML is tag based yet not pure XML.